# how to make the path have "/"

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, filepath

I have some problem with my open new window popup which it can read my path and it like throw away my "/" sign in it. So it will be see like this "C:UsersKHAIRADesktopheitechHibah Total v1.2/Secure/PDF Folder"

Can anyone help me to make it look/read like this "C:Users/KHAIRA/Desktop/heitech/Hibah Total v1.2/Secure/PDF Folder".

I have open button in gridview that will open new window and view the pdf file here the coding from ViewDocument.aspx

```
string commandName = e.CommandName.ToString().Trim();
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
string folderName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folderPDF"].ToString();
string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "/Secure/";
string fullPath = path + folderName;
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*.pdf"); 
switch (commandName)
{
    case "Open":                       
        string script = "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
        script += "window.open ('OpenForm.aspx?path=" + row.Cells[0].Text;
        script += "','CustomPopUp', config='height=500,width=1024, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes,location=no, directories=no, status=no')\n";
        script += "</script>";

        this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", script);
        break;
```

for the OpenForm.aspx.cs coding :

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        string paths = Request.QueryString["path"].ToString();
        bool fileExist = File.Exists(paths);
        if (fileExist)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
            Response.TransmitFile(paths);
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "File Not Exist";
        }
    }
```

However, i realize that the problem is from here

```
string paths = Request.QueryString["path"].ToString();
```

Comment: to help you you need to show some source code...

Comment: Can you post the code you're using, what you're inputting, and where it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first.

The local system path separator is `\` e.g. `C:\Windows`.

`/` is for web e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902129/how-to-make-the-path-have/9902194#9902194`

For a single `\` you have to put `\\` (remember escape sequence)

**Or**

Use String Verbatim

```
string path = @"C:\Users\KHAIRA\Desktop\heitech\Hibah Total v1.2\Secure\PDF Folder"
```

**Or**

Use Path.Combine method of System.IO namespace like

```
Path.Combine("C:", "Users");
```

It will give return a string

```
C:\Users
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
string path = "C:Users\\KHAIRA\\Desktop\\heitech\\Hibah Total v1.2\\Secure\\PDF Folder";
```

Comment: this will work only at my laptop. Once I try to run it at other laptop or pc it will not work.

Comment: Probably because there is no user named KHAIRA on the other laptop or PC or another part of the path doesn't exist?

Comment: yes, thats why I use Sever.MapPath("~") for make it flexible but it can work when i try to open new window. It seem like it can't read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String path=@"C:Users/KHAIRA/Desktop/heitech/Hibah Total v1.2/Secure"

String fullpath=path + "\\\" + "PDF Folder"
```

Fullpath will contain the path you want